# Изменения в QMessageBox

Tags: c++, qt

Создаю `QMessageBox` таким путем:

```
QMessageBox messageBox(QMessageBox::Warning,
                       tr("Foo Text"),
                       tr("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,\n consetetur sadipscing elitr,"),
                       QMessageBox::Yes | QMessageBox::No,
                       this);
messageBox.setButtonText(QMessageBox::Yes, tr("OK"));
messageBox.setButtonText(QMessageBox::No, tr("Cancel"));
```

Как добавить сюда `QComboBox` и будет ли работать такое заполнение на нем?

```
static const QString format("WP%1:  E: %2  N: %3  Z: 32  %4");
ui->test->addItem(format.arg(foo[i].iD)
                                       .arg(foo[i].lng)
                                       .arg(foo[i].lat)
                                       .arg(foo[i].alt));
```

Как поменять кнопки `YES` и `NO` местами?

Comment: Насколько я помню, `QMessageBox` использует платформо-зависимые `MessageBox`ы, а значит никакого `QComboBox` туда поместить нельзя.

Comment: Похоже, вам нужен [`QInputDialog::getItem()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qinputdialog.html#getItem)

Comment: Порядок кнопок `QMessageBox`'а также платформозависим и мимикрирует под систему в которой он запущен... вместо извращения описанного выше стоит использовать `QMessageBox::Ok` и `QMessageBox::Cancel`.

Comment: Возможно, стоит отнаследоваться от `QDialog` и добавить свои виджеты через дизайнер?